# Are there faster XML parsers in Java than Xalan/Xerces

Tags: java, xml, performance, parsing

I haven't found many ways to increase the performance of a Java application that does intensive XML processing other than to leverage hardware such as Tarari or Datapower. Does anyone know of any open source ways to accelerate XML parsing?

Comment: You will get better answers if you elaborate on what kind of XML processing you're doing. Are you constrained by a specific API (DOM)? How much of the XML do you need to store in memory? How many different schemas do you need to support? Can you trust XML to be valid?..

Comment: Related question: 'Fastest XML parser for small, simple documents in Java', http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530064/fastest-xml-parser-for-small-simple-documents-in-java

Comment: Check out this 2013  paper it does a lot benchmarking http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Stax (streaming) parsers. See [the sun reference manual](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbdw.html). One of the implementations is the [woodstox project](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/).

Comment: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/05/09/xml-parser-benchmarks-part-1.html has a good overview of XML parser speeds.  Woodstox looks pretty good.

Comment: STAX is the way to go and Woodstox is supah fast.

Comment: Wrt VTD vs Stax, one really should try it out. Stax is an API, so different implementations have different performance. And VTD-XML' trade-offs are bit different -- faster to parse, slower to access (some operations are only taken on access, like handling of character entities).

Comment: without support for random access, Stax is slow to parse and slower in access, entity handling is virtually indistinguishable from dom... this is the easy fact to keep in mind...

Answer (score 5):

Since it hasn't been directly mentioned, I'll throw in [Aalto](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/AaltoHome), which is fastest java xml parser according to some measurements, like:

- [JVM-serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) (which compares, XML, JSON, protobuf, Thrift etc etc)
- [Alternative serialization methods for WSTest](http://technotes.blogs.sapo.pt/1708.html) (Java web services)

which are not written by Aalto developers.

Answer (score 3):

[VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is very fast.

It has a DOM-like API and even XPath queries.

Answer (score 0):

[Piccolo](http://piccolo.sourceforge.net) claims to be [pretty fast](http://piccolo.sourceforge.net/bench.html). Can't say I've used it myself though. You might also try [JDOM](http://jdom.org/). As ever, benchmark with representative data of your *real* load.

It partly depends on what you're trying to do. Do you need to pull the whole document into memory, or can you operate in a [streaming manner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX)? Different approaches have different trade-offs and are better for different situations.

Comment: Piccolo seems to trade speed for correctness, which may or may not be what you want. (http://cafeconleche.org/SAXTest/paper.html#S4.2.4)

Comment: In all fairness, deviations are rather unlikely to affect cases where performance matters (which tend to be simple(r) use cases) -- SAXTest tends to focus on complicated cases of DTD usage and correctness.
But on the other hand, while Piccolo may have been faster in 2004, it hasn't been developed much, and others have caught up, and some surpasses it (Xerces is as fast, Woodstox and especially Aalto faster)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your XML messages you might find a custom parser can be 10x faster (though more work to write) However if performance is critical, I wouldn't suggest using a generic parser. (Also I wouldn't suggest using XML as its not designed for performance, but that's another story, .. ;)

Comment: Writing custom XML parser is time consuming and error prone process. Getting XML right isn't easy, especially if you want to parse XML documents from the wild. (http://cafeconleche.org/SAXTest/)

Comment: This is all true, which is why its not a good idea most of the time.  However if speed is critical you can get a 10x improvement.

Comment: Huh? Have you ever actually tried doing this? Writing a custom parser that is ANY faster is non-trivial. Fastest existing parsers parse with 30-60 MBps rate; not much slower than you can decode plain UTF-8 text.

10x, no way, absolutely not. Feel free to try, get some numbers. :-)

Comment: I would strongly expect that any gain on speed comes with the knowledge that _some_ work does not need doing.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Custom parsers gain by being tuned to a specific XMl format.  This is not appriate in most cases, but you can see a significant improvement.  By improvement, I mean in term of latency rather than throughput.  The throughput is improved by may be 2x, again by doing less work.

Comment: Yes, I agree in that schema-specific processing can improve performance, and maybe factor of 2x is doable. Still it's good idea to start with existing general purpose ones, see how far they go. My bet would be on Aalto being fastest one can find currently.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Javolution](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) as well

Comment: I disagree. Javolution's XML "parser" does not check ANY problems with xml (duplicate attributes), doesn't handle namespaces, doesn't implement any standard API. And is not even faster.

Comment: @StaxMan on the bright side it does not create as much garbage during parsing, and sometimes being able to read malformed XML is a bonus

Comment: Value of ultra-low garbage production is an open question on most platforms; and most streaming parsers are quite frugal with object production anyway. If you find it to be useful, good for you. I just have yet to see it matter in this context. As to invalid XML, I am of opinion that it is better not to be able to handle that and apply back pressure to producers of broken things. But YMMV, each to his own.