# Any other parser instead of Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

Which **small**, **light** parser is it better to use if Jsoup.parse in my case just crashes because of the file size

my code is not important in here, but here:

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

            Element table = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
            return table;
```

OK, this actually works, but there is a difference either if I run this code on the PC(dalvik virtual machine) or on the android device(developing for android OS). I am not sure what exactly is the problem, but it seems that the memory(heap size) is bigger on the device, but I have not checked it so far - it is just an assumption.
So what I can say about Jsoup - it is i guess the fastest and smallest library which is suitable for my case to parse and clean pure HTML code on the DOM basis. If you one needs to extarc some part of the HTML based on the tags(tr, table, ... etc) then Jsoup is the best possible open source HTML parser. And when applying it in the code, there are only two lines that are needed, as it is shown in the example above. The result you get after getting elemnets or extracting some part of the HTML is a simple String which contains the tags that you selected with the Jsoup. I am sure it has more functionality than that, just never have used anything more complex.

Comment: posted. but it will not help you

Comment: Do you need to cleanup the HTML or can you be sure that there is valid XML coming in?

Comment: I have to extract a table out from the html file

Comment: If you can be sure that there is valid XML coming in you do not need HTML cleaners like JSoup or Jericho. For large XML documents you should take a look STaX parsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960357/are-there-faster-xml-parsers-in-java-than-xalan-xerces

Comment: Can you post the HTML somewhere so that I can test? Privately is OK. jsoup shouldn't crash -- I've parsed some pretty big HTML files, upwards of 50 megs as a stress test.

Answer (score 1):

im guessing that your trying to parse html try Jericho

Comment: Is it possible to extract parts of an html document and create a new String with the selected components?